# Clapping and applause has been deemed too primitive. What's next?

Tags: society, humans, communication

We're not cavemen anymore.

Applause and all forms of congratulatory/commendational clapping have been deemed as **way too** primitive.

How do we show our approval in a modern "civilized" society?

In short are there existing methods of congratulatory...noise that could be deemed more civilized, I am looking for existing traditions that could be applied to fiction.

Comment: Are catcalls and "whoot whoot!"s also considered too primitive?

Comment: This question seems unanswerable in its current form. How does this society define "civilized"? What sort of values are important to them?

Comment: How would we bring faeries back to life after someone says they don't believe in them?  You monster!

Comment: I applause you for this question......;-)

Comment: You seems to forget about kissing and punching, a more civilized way is voting of course remember?

Comment: The normal method I've seen in formal dining events is to tap your spoon on a glass or bowl.

Comment: I agree that this seems too opinion based. A better way to go about this would be to say that a future society has deemed clapping and applause as barbaric, and then outline their culture. After that we may be able to determine what a better form of accolades would entail.

Answer (score 8):

Free-Waterfall Senior has the answer:

[image]

The thumbs up is a well recognized signal for approval in many cultures, it's an obvious replacement for clapping.

That is, until Facebook figures out how to let people "Like" real life events in real time (which is just a digital thumbs-up).

Comment: Wikipedia: [The thumbs up signal has a generally positive connotation in English-speaking countries. However, its perceived meaning varies significantly from culture to culture. The sign has a pejorative meaning in parts of West Africa, Iran, and Greece according to Roger E. Axtell's book Gestures: The Do's and Taboos of Body Language Around the World.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbs_signal)

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, the [vuvuzela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuvuzela). Already in wide use.

Answer (score 1):

Have your built-in g00gle glasses apply *Kudos* to the other persons virtual appreciation account.

You would not want to show any ugly bodily signals, now would you? We're a modern "civilized" society, not cavemen, after all!

Answer (score 0):

I don't vouch for its accuracy, but here's a claim of Romans "[waving the flap of the toga](http://libguides.gallaudet.edu/content.php?pid=351741), for which last the emperor Aurelian substituted a handkerchief (orarium), distributed to all Roman citizens".

Doesn't get much more civilized than the late Roman empire, right? Right?

The article describes other forms of visual applause, mostly intended for deaf people.